# Chart for Recorder fingering notation in Musixtex with Tikz and Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, musixtex

It is needed to implement a Chart for Recorder fingering notation in Musixtex with Tikz and Beamer, the basic code is as follow:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{hyperref} %Referencias a las tablas
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
    \frametitle{\LARGE Chart Flute in Musixtex}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,rotate=0,transform shape,scale=0.9, ,fill=green!20] (partitura) at (0,0) {
        \hspace*{-0.01cm}\begin{music}
        \parindent0mm
        \afterruleskip-7pt
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece 
        %\scale{0.8}
        \NOTEs\wh c \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.5cm} DO}\en 
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh d \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.55cm} RE}\en
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh e \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.5cm} MI}\en 
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh f \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.55cm} FA}\en
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh g \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.5cm} SOL}\en 
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh h \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.55cm} LA}\en
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh i \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.5cm} SI}\en 
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh j \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.55cm} DO\scalebox{1.6}{`}}\en
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \NOTEs\wh k \zcharnote{-10}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.5cm} RE\scalebox{1.6}{`}}\en 
        \zcharnote{15}{\hspace*{-0.04cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %Código para dibujar la Flauta
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
        \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.04cm];
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \zendpiece
        \end{music}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't use `musixtex` but I do play the recorder and know a little TikZ, so I've created a small package to produce fingering diagrams for both C and F recorders called `recorder-fingering`.  It is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/recorder-fingering) and included in any recent TeX distribution.

The package provides five commands (`\Sopranino`, `\Soprano`, `\Alto`, `\Tenor` and `\Bass`) which will produce a fingering diagram for any note in the playable range of that recorder. The notes range from C–Eb for recorders in C or F–Ab for recorders in F. The package allows you to customize the display in a variety of ways along with adding trill fingering annotations.

Notes are noted as C-B (first octave) c-b (second octave) and c'–eb' (third octave) with an equivalent scheme starting at F for the recorders in F.

The diagrams are in the standard format that most recorder methods use to show fingerings, and show Baroque/English fingerings. The thumb hole is the topmost position of the diagram, with half-thumb fingerings notated with a half-filled circle. The next three are the left hand and the last four are the right hand. The db' note has an extra position at the bottom to signify covering the bell of the recorder).

If you're really looking to put the chart onto an image of a recorder, I'm afraid I can't help you although it might be possible to do that using this package to make the fingerings themselves.

Here's a chart produced using the package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{recorder-fingering}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hmargin=.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\section*{Recorder in C fingering chart}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\toprule
C & C\# & D & Eb & E & F & F\# & G & Ab & A & Bb & B\\ 
\midrule
\Soprano{C} & 
\Soprano{C#} & 
\Soprano{D} & 
\Soprano{Eb} & 
\Soprano{E} &
\Soprano{F} &
\Soprano{F#} &
\Soprano{G} &
\Soprano{Ab} &
\Soprano{A} &
\Soprano{Bb} &
\Soprano{B}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\toprule
c & c\# & d & eb & e & f & f\# & g & ab & a & bb & b\\ 
\midrule
\Soprano{c} &
\Soprano{c#} &
\Soprano{d} &
\Soprano{eb} &
\Soprano{e} &
\Soprano{f} &
\Soprano{f#} &
\Soprano{g} &
\Soprano{ab} &
\Soprano{a} &
\Soprano{bb} &
\Soprano{b}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
c' & c\#' & d' & eb'\\
\midrule
\Soprano{c'} &
\Soprano{c#'} &
\Soprano{d'} &
\Soprano{eb'}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Using the package with `musixtex`

The simplest way to add fingering charts on top of music using `musixtex` is to use the TikZ `tikzmark` library which allows you to place arbitrary coordinates on a page and then refer to them with subsequent `\tikz` commands. In the example below  I've done two things: first, for the solfege note names I've used the `musixtex` addition `musixlyr` which allows the note names to be input as a single space delimited string.

I've also created a helper macro `\addf` to place the fingerings themselves.  Then before each note, we simply use the `tikzmark` command to create position on the page for that note which the helper macro uses to place the fingering.

Note that because this uses the `[remember picture]` function of TikZ it will require two compilations for the fingerings to show up in their correct positions.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{recorder-fingering}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addf}{m}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{\Soprano[width=10pt]{#1}};}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{C Maj scale Soprano/Tenor recorder fingerings}
\begin{music}
\setlyrics{scale}{DO RE ME FA SOL LA SI DO}
\lyrraise{1}{b-2ex}
\assignlyrics{1}{scale}
\startextract
\NOTEs
\tikzmark{C}\wh{c}\tikzmark{D}\wh{d}\tikzmark{E}\wh{e}\tikzmark{F}\wh{f}
\tikzmark{G}\wh{g}\tikzmark{A}\wh{h}\tikzmark{B}\wh{i}\tikzmark{c}\wh{j}
\en
\zendextract
\end{music}
\addf{C}\addf{D}\addf{E}\addf{E}\addf{F}\addf{G}\addf{A}\addf{B}\addf{c}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of beamer code]